# Disable proxy types for OrganizationServiceProxy

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, xrmtoolbox

I'm working with pre-defined `IOrganizationService` object I cannot modify — it's out of my control.

And it seems to be by default this `IOrganizationService` returns resolved types as if `EnableProxyTypes()` was called implicitly somewhere on originating `OrganizationServiceProxy`.

And this ruins all business logic, since early bound entities could not be serialized that easily, since on different installations they could be resolved to different types. So even if they would be successfully serialized, cannot be 100% certain that they could be de-serialized.

To be more specific it's plugin for `XrmToolBox`. If hosting application loaded plugin that uses early bounding, these generated types will be discovered via reflection and applied to results of `Retrieve` and `RetrieveMultiple` calls.

For example `RetrieveMultiple` to `account` entity response will normally contain `Entity[]`, each item of this array will have `LogicalName` property set to `account`.

But if early bound types was discovered in assembly, let's call it `EarlyBouldLibrary.dll`, the same `RetrieveMultiple` will return `EarlyBouldLibrary.Account[]`. Each item of this array will be derived from `Entity` and will contain same field as in first example, but with additional properties.

The problem is in following. If we will try to serialize `EarlyBouldLibrary.Account[]` to `XML` it will fail. Because `EarlyBouldLibrary.Account` is unknown.

Ok, it's possible to add types to known. But there is no guarantee, that one day another early bound types will be found in `NewEarlyBouldLibrary.dll`... And they will have name `NewEarlyBouldLibrary.Account`... Which is unknown...

Ok, let's assume serialization succeeded, no matter which types are referenced `EarlyBouldLibrary.Account` or `NewEarlyBouldLibrary.Account`, but if we will try to de-serialize, on environment where these early bound libraries not present... action will fail.

So only way will be not to use specific early bound types, that out of our control, and use standard and safe `Entity`. But it's impossible while system automatically resolves proxy types.

So, question: is there any way to disable resolve of early bound types?

Comment: I don't understand your question, can you expand or make an example of this serialization problem?

Comment: @GuidoPreite I have extended description to explain the problem. Can you take a look again?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but casting early bound types back to Entity might help I guess. relatedEntity.ToEntity<Entity>() https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309586.aspx

Comment: @Davlumbaz nice workaround! I will try it and add some handling in case if no early bound types was binded.

Comment: It might be helpful to see some code with the error

Comment: For this are you saying the entities being retrieved are not of type Entity, but EarlyBoundLibrary.Account, and you're expecting it to be NewEarlyBoundLibrary.Account?

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect your proxy to another assembly containing the types you need (or even containing no early bound types at all).

The example below resets the proxy assembly:

```
private void ResetProxyAssembly(IOrganizationService service)
{
    var serviceProxy = (OrganizationServiceProxy) service;
    serviceProxy.EnableProxyTypes();
}
```

In certain scenarios this may not work. Instead you can explicitly select the desired proxy assembly:

```
private void ResetProxyAssembly(IOrganizationService service)
{
    var serviceProxy = (OrganizationServiceProxy) service;
    serviceProxy.EnableProxyTypes(typeof(MyEarlyBoundEntity).Assembly);
}
```

Comment: Didn't worked for my particular case. Failed on very first step — casting to `OrganizationServiceProxy`. But Idea is nice and will probably work in other cases!

Comment: Could it be your scenario was a plugin or workflow activity?

Answer (score 0):

Could you add `[assembly: Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ProxyTypesAssembly]` to the AssemblyInfo file of the `EarlyBouldLibrary.dll` or `NewEarlyBouldLibrary.dll` assembly?